# Removing duplicated numbers within tuples

Tags: python, tuples

For example I want to remove the extra 1s and 2s in this tuple ( '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '1',
    '2',
    '2',
    '2') to return ('1', '2')

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do that, tuples being immutable.

Comment: It would have to be a new tuple. Just convert it to a set then back to a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify tuple in place, So definitely you have to get new tuple. You can use set to remove duplicate elements.

```
>>> tp = ( '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2')
>>> tp = tuple(set(tp))
>>> tp
('1', '2')
```

Answer (score 3):

As Alok [correctly mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35533746/674064), you have to create a new tuple. As Alok demonstrates, you can of course assign it to the variable that previously held the original tuple.

If you don't care about order, use `set` as Alok suggests. If you however want to preserve the order (of *first* occurrence of each unique value), you can use a very similar trick with an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Different example to demonstrate preserved order
tp = ('2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')

tp = tuple(OrderedDict.fromkeys(tp).keys())
# Now,  tp == ('2', '1')
```

Comment: Nice way to maintain order

Answer (score 0):

They are correct, tuples in python are immutable therefore you cannot update the current tuple. This function loops through data creating a list of indexes that do not currently exist! It then returns a tuple of the list! Good luck!

```
data = ( '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '4','4')

def removeDoubles(data):
    out = []
    for i in data:
        if i in out:
            continue
        out.append(i)
    del data
    return tuple(out)
print removeDoubles(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `set`:

```
a = ( '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2')
b = tuple(set(a))
```

If the order is important you could sort `b`.